# Crash on pdfdocument writetToFile method

Tags: objective-c

I am getting a crash for the following code. Can anyone help me to come out of this issue, please?

```
PDFPage *page = [self.pdfDocument pageAtIndex:0];
PDFAnnotationSquare *annotation = [[PDFAnnotationSquare alloc] init];
NSColor *interiorColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:@"TestImage"];
annotation.interiorColor =  interiorColor;
annotation.bounds = NSMakeRect(100.0, 100.0, 300, 300);
[page addAnnotation:annotation];
[self.pdfDocument writeToFile:@"SomePath"];
```

The same code executes properly if I set, 
`annotation.interiorColor = [NSColor redColor];`

Comment: What is the crashlog?

Comment: Crash log :Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Comment: [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:@"TestImage"]; This method accept UIImage but you are passing String.

Comment: Oh sorry, by mistake I have typed like that. I am passing NSImage only. NSColor *interiorColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:self.testImage]